# Is there a way to organize breakpoints hierarchically on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

There are some configuration or plugin to able the creation of "breakpoint paths"?
Exemple: If there are some piece of code "B" and "C" that runs many times in your project, but it are just interesting for your debug process if another piece of code "A" runs before it, there are some way to able breakpoint in "B" only if breakpoint in "A" already passed, and just able breakpoint in "C" only if "A" and "B" already passed?

Comment: Arthur, why not do it via coding? Then you can put a breakpoint in it. Abraços.

Comment: to the anonymous downvoter - please explain your vote. What do you see as unconstructive in this question?

Comment: @aldux How can I do that?

Comment: You can create temporary debug variables as flags. Then you use an if statement and put a breakpoint inside the condition. Therefore, the breakpoint will "break" only if the condition (A,B,C) matches.